# Connection to the RabbitMQ doesn't work only in PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect to the rabbit queue.
For some reason, example from the documentation doesn't work(only in PHP for some reason)

Library

```
amqplib/php-amqplib
```

PHP code that doesn't work:

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
    'test.cloudamqp.com',
    5671,
    'test',
    'test',
    'test'
);
```

I receive the next errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or
> closed connection in
> /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:172
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(158):
> PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read()
> #1 /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(104):
> PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread()
> #2 /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(576):
> PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read()
> #3 /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(632):
> PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame()
> #4 /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(235):
> PhpAmqpLib\Connection\ in
> /home/mykola/Projects/vs-php-clipping-engine/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 172

Golang code that works perfectly:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    amqp "github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqps://test:test@test.cloudamqp.com/test")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

}
```

Does a golang package have some magic parameters that are automatically applied to this connection
I'm thinking maybe I need some specific arguments to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the connection setup. Other libs do it automatically, but PHP doesn't, so if you want to deal with amqps you need to add the path to the certificates, like this:

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
    'test.cloudamqp.com',
    5671,
    'test',
    'test',
    'vhostName',
    [
      'capath' => '/etc/ssl/certs'
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create a new `AMQPStreamConnection` object, instead crate a new `AMQPSSLConnection`

Everything else should be the same, however you may need to set the ssl_protocol (It defaults to ssl)

See [AMQPSSLConnection](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPSSLConnection.php)

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried all types of connections. I think there is something in options array that I need to pass